# My react component isn't rendering my state when i receive a response from socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm building a component that updates every time a new user joins my server. My componentDidUpdate is emitting a new user that i pull from redux, and then I'm receiving the response in my constructor and setting state with it. When I console.log the data I'm receiving back, everything is exactly how I expect it to be however I am not able to map over my state and render a component for every element.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import "./SearchSideBar.css"
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';
import Contact from "../Contact/Contact";
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { updateUsersConnected } from "../../Redux/reducer"
const socket = socketIOClient("http://localhost:4000/");

export class SearchSideBar extends Component{
constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        toggleSearch:false,
        usersConnected:[]

    }

    socket.on("UserEnter", data =>{
        console.log(data)
        this.setState({
            usersConnected:data
        })
        // this.props.updateUsersConnected(data)
        console.log("Users in this room : ", this.state.usersConnected)
    })

}

handleButtonPress = () =>{ 
    this.setState({
        toggleSearch:!this.state.toggleSearch
    })
}

componentDidUpdate = (prevProps) =>{
    if(this.props.user.email != prevProps.user.email){
        socket.emit("NewUser", this.props.user)
    } 
}


render(){
    console.log(this.state)
    return(
        <div className = "search-parent">

            <div className = "container-header">
                <h3 className = "title">Who's Online?</h3>
                <button onClick={() =>{this.handleButtonPress()}}><img className = "searchIcon" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/000000/search.png"></img></button>
            </div>

            <div className = {this.state.toggleSearch? "show":"hidden"}>
                <input className = "searchbar" placeholder = "Search for a name or department"></input>
            </div>

            {
                this.state.usersConnected.length? this.state.usersConnected.map(user =>{
                    return(
                        <div>
                            <Contact/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
                :
                console.log("Doesn't work")
            }

        </div>
    )
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
return{
    user:state.user
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,{updateUsersConnected}(SearchSideBar)
```

[image: here is what my console looks like when this code runs]

Comment: `usersConnected` seems so be an object judging by your image, not an array.

Comment: Ugh. You are right. Thanks for spotting that